# Convert GRPC protobuf response to PHP array without mapping

Tags: php, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am wondering if there is a quick way to get a PHP array from the `\Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message` object that is returned from the GRPC client without having to explicitly map the response objects fields to an array.

The [GRPC tutorial](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/php.html#simple-rpc) seems to get the fields by calling their getters:

```
$point = new Routeguide\Point();
$point->setLatitude(409146138);
$point->setLongitude(-746188906);

// $feature is the response
list($feature, $status) = $client->GetFeature($point)->wait();

// Calling getters here
print sprintf("Found %s \n  at %f, %f\n", $feature->getName(),
              $feature->getLocation()->getLatitude() / COORD_FACTOR,
              $feature->getLocation()->getLongitude() / COORD_FACTOR);
```

Is there a faster way? I see the `decode()` method on the `\Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message` class but haven't had luck with getting it to work. I don't know if that is its intended purpose either.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late but for anyone looking for the answer today,
below is what I do to serialize the gRPC object response directly to a json object:

```
 $feature->serializeToJsonString();
```

Comment: This doesn't give proper JSON, the output will be serialised JSON like the following:   ```{\u0022total\u0022:{\u0022static\u0022:2.1299999999999999,\u0022hourly\u0022:0.12,\u0022monthly\u0022:0.12,\u0022annual\u0022:0.12},\u0022totalAfterTax\u0022:{\u0022static\u0022:0.12,\u0022hourly\u0022:0.12,\u0022monthly\u0022:0.12,\u0022annual\u0022:0.12}}```

Comment: @srth12 that's a proper JSON output, it seems that your encoding is messed up prior to that.